# Qt - How can I connect a signal to a QGroupBox each time the show() function is called on it?

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes that are interacting with each other, let's call them for the sake of simplicity *ClassA* and *ClassB*. In *ClassA*, I would like to emit a signal when a specific **QGroupBox** is shown that triggers a slot in *ClassB* to set the given channel's checkbox.

I have a code that consists of several thousand lines, so I included only the most relevant parts.

**ClassA header**

```
private:
QGroupbox* m_Channel1GroupBox;
void setup();

signals:
void setCheckBox(int, bool);
```

**ClassA source**

```
void ClassA::setup()
{
    m_Channel1GroupBox = new QGroupBox("Channel 1", this);

    connect(m_Channel1GroupBox, &QGroupBox::show, [this]()
    {
        emit setCheckBox(1, true);
    });
}
```

**ClassB header**

```
private:
QCheckBox* m_Channel1CheckBox;

public slots:
void setCheckBox(int, bool);
```

**ClassB source**

```
void ClassB::setCheckBox(int channel, bool check)
{
    if (channel == 1)
    {
        m_Channel1CheckBox->setChecked(check);
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
connect(m_ClassA, &ClassA::setCheckBox, m_ClassB, &ClassB::setCheckBox);
```

The lambda expression compiles, but unfortunately it doesn't do what it is expected to do, which is whenever m_Channel1GroupBox->show() is called, then tick the checkbox of Channel1. Actually this block of code never executes, which would emit **setCheckBox**.

Please note that the **setCheckBox** function works perfectly when called in another function of *ClassA* and it checks or unchecks the desired channel in *ClassB*. This is possible using another connect in the Main.cpp file where the object instances are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subclass QGroupBox to achieve the functionality you require.

Override QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent*) in your QGroupBox subclass and do the work there.

Please see the [documentation for QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showEvent).

Answer (score 0):

run the code and you will see that the

`QGroupBox` has no signal to emit called `show`...
show is actually a slot

[image]

> QObject::connect: signal not found in QGroupBox

But...
if you are calling show per hand, then emit the signal right after that...

Comment: So basically the only way to make this work is if I use:
emit setCheckBox() after each line of m_Channel1GroupBox->show()

Would it be possible to do this automatically instead?

Comment: no, you can achieve that in several ways depending on how the app requires it

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give me an example how would you achieve to emit the setCheckBox signal each time the show() function is called on a specific QGroupBox*?